# Multplying groupby elements for each group in survey

Tags: pandas, numpy, matrix, survey

I am working on Stack Overflow 2019 Survey data. [here is Survey 2019 data.](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey)

There are lots of columns in that data.

I want to carry out this calculation ---> "Sum of Age1stCode" / "Number of people who are related years old".

Age1stCode is a column in survey illustrates a first year of coding. Age is a column of "age years old".

I have created a group according to "Age".

I just want to multiply each opposing number and then to sum them. For instance, for age 11 = (6x3)+(7x3)+ (9x2)+.......(8x1). I want to to do this for each age group. So at the end, I want to achieve an output like the file I attached "Age 11.0 ----> 326 (it is just random for example), Age 12.0 ---> 468)

My goal is to calculate this ---> Sum of Age1stCode for each age group.

[here is the output that I want to work with. Attached File.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiN0Z.png)

Comment: Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. You should include your code so far and all of the data needed to answer the question should be in text, not in images or links to external sources.

Comment: Just do: `df.groupby('Age').Age1stCode.sum()`.

Comment: @QuangHoang there was an error which says "you can only convert str to str", so I convert both "Age" and "Age1stCod" values to str then error was fixed. But output not as I expected. For age 10 it is written 444 (should be 3)  and for 11 it is 69771078911656 (should be 91)

Comment: Why would you convert numerical values to string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df_grouped = df.groupby('Age').agg({'Age1stCode': 'sum'}).reset_index()
new_col = df_grouped['Age1stCode'] / df_grouped['Age']
```

Comment: Gracias so much! I revised your code and it gave me the result I want.                                                        `df_grouped = df.groupby('Age').agg({'Age1stCode': 'sum'})
 new_col = df_grouped['Age1stCode']`